# Every time I render my screen turns blue

Tags: rendering

[image: ry]

This is what my render screen looks like. The thing I am trying to render is a parallax or 2.5d animation

Comment: Could you share a .blend file so I can see the issue? This doesn't really show what could be wrong in the scene.

Comment: Does this always happen or only with that specific scene? If it's the former, what is your CPU and GPU?

Comment: it renders then stop rendering and keeps being that color

Comment: i cannot figuire out how to share a .blend file on this thing

Comment: i am using eevee